# Cron in Laravel and Cpanel

Tags: php, laravel, cron, cpanel

## Laravel cron issue on Cpanel

### Background info

- Laravel 10
- cpanel shared hosting
- crons set up and tested locally

I have a tested set of crons that run jobs/queues in my local environment. When I attempted to upload them to the cpanel server the crons seemed to not be working. I emailed the output to myself to debug it.

### Issue

When I run a cron on my cpanel hosting, the command seems to lose options.

I am using the cpanel cron editor (I only have basic command line access, and no crontab).

If I run:

```bash
php /home/accountname/www/artisan schedule:run
```

I get the an email that contains the artisan "with no options" help content... ie:

> Usage:   command [options] [arguments]
>
> Options:   -h, --help            Display help for the given command.
> When no command is given display help for the list command   -q,
> --quiet           Do not output any message   -V, --version         Display this application version
> --ansi|--no-ansi  Force (or disable --no-ansi) ANSI output
> ...

The commands work exactly as expected when run directly from command line.

[Edit]

I have been able to check `crontab -l` and the crons are normally added.

```
MAILTO="[my email]"
SHELL="/bin/bash"
* * * * * php /home/accountname/www/artisan schedule:run
* * * * * php /home/accountname/www/artisan queue:work --stop-when-empty
```

^ they seem to be correctly added.

### Question

How do i get the cron editor to read the options from this command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, this seems to come from not using the correct php version.

It was fixed by changing to the local version of php:

- `/usr/local/bin/php`